# Deserialize an EnumMap using gson

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, gson

I have a json string in the format as stated below which I'm trying to deserialize using gson

```
{
  "MAPS": [
    {
      "value": true,
      "enabled": [
        {
          "isoCountryCode": "USA"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the structure of my class and enum

```
public class Configuration {
  private Map<EnumType, List<Object>> enumToObjectMap;
}

   public enum EnumType {
     MAPS;
}
```

When I'm trying to deserialize it using

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Configuration.class)
```

I'm getting null value for enumToObjectMap. Kindly help me regarding same.

Comment: Where are you getting the null value at?

Comment: value of enumToObjectMap is coming as null.

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON instead?

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more correct solution, but here are a couple of workarounds:

1. Wrap the JSON string in a parent field:

   ```
   jsonString = "{\"enumToObjectMap\":" + jsonString + "}";
   Configuration c = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Configuration.class);
   ```
2. Deserialize the map independently and pass it into your class via constructor or setter:

   ```
   Configuration c = new Configuration();
   c.setMap(new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,
           new TypeToken<EnumMap<EnumType, List<Object>>>() {}.getType()));
   ```

Comment: Gson 2.8.0 does not instantiate an `EnumMap` in this case. Not sure if it's a bug or a design choice, though.

Comment: Above approach will introduce a hard coding in my code and is not extensible and generic. What if later on my class composes an object of another class which also has an enum map?

Comment: Writing a custom deserializer for this class solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can verify with adding this code  :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
String json = "";
///////////////////////////
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

////////////////////////////////////
if (br != null) {

    json = br.readLine();
    sb.append(json);
    System.out.println(json);
}
JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
System.out.println(jso);
```